# What's wrong here with downloading react native vision camera?

Tags: java, android, react-native, build.gradle, react-native-camera

I have updated the dependencies in build.gradle file

But this keeps appearing and I don't know what the problem is?

here is **android\build.gradle** file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 26
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33

        // We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
    }
}
```

and here is **android\app\build.gradle** file contents:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "com.facebook.react"


/**
 * This is the configuration block to customize your React Native Android app.
 * By default you don't need to apply any configuration, just uncomment the lines you need.
 */
react {
    /* Folders */
    //   The root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives. Default is '..'
    // root = file("../")
    //   The folder where the react-native NPM package is. Default is ../node_modules/react-native
    // reactNativeDir = file("../node_modules/react-native")
    //   The folder where the react-native Codegen package is. Default is ../node_modules/@react-native/codegen
    // codegenDir = file("../node_modules/@react-native/codegen")
    //   The cli.js file which is the React Native CLI entrypoint. Default is ../node_modules/react-native/cli.js
    // cliFile = file("../node_modules/react-native/cli.js")

    /* Variants */
    //   The list of variants to that are debuggable. For those we're going to
    //   skip the bundling of the JS bundle and the assets. By default is just 'debug'.
    //   If you add flavors like lite, prod, etc. you'll have to list your debuggableVariants.
    // debuggableVariants = ["liteDebug", "prodDebug"]

    /* Bundling */
    //   A list containing the node command and its flags. Default is just 'node'.
    // nodeExecutableAndArgs = ["node"]
    //
    //   The command to run when bundling. By default is 'bundle'
    // bundleCommand = "ram-bundle"
    //
    //   The path to the CLI configuration file. Default is empty.
    // bundleConfig = file(../rn-cli.config.js)
    //
    //   The name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
    // bundleAssetName = "MyApplication.android.bundle"
    //
    //   The entry file for bundle generation. Default is 'index.android.js' or 'index.js'
    // entryFile = file("../js/MyApplication.android.js")
    //
    //   A list of extra flags to pass to the 'bundle' commands.
    //   See https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/docs/commands.md#bundle
    // extraPackagerArgs = []

    /* Hermes Commands */
    //   The hermes compiler command to run. By default it is 'hermesc'
    // hermesCommand = "$rootDir/my-custom-hermesc/bin/hermesc"
    //
    //   The list of flags to pass to the Hermes compiler. By default is "-O", "-output-source-map"
    // hermesFlags = ["-O", "-output-source-map"]
}

/**
 * Set this to true to Run Proguard on Release builds to minify the Java bytecode.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore (JSC)
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US. Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'
//def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'

android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    namespace "com.awesomeproject"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.awesomeproject"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        // react-native-iap: we only use the Google Play flavor
        missingDimensionStrategy 'store', 'play'
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // The version of react-native is set by the React Native Gradle Plugin
    implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android")
    //implementation project(':react-native-camera')

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:0.231.0")
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:0.231.0") {
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:0.182.0")
    if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

and here is **package.json** file contents:

```
{
  "name": "AwesomeProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "react-native-camera": "^4.2.1",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^7.0.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.10.0",
    "react-native-vision-camera": "^3.5.1",
    "react-native-worklets-core": "^0.2.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "^0.72.2",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.72.11",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.76.8",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16"
  }
}
```

info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...

> Configure project :react-native-vision-camera
> [VisionCamera] react-native-worklets-core found, Frame Processors enabled!

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
5 actionable tasks: 5 up-to-date

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve project :react-native-camera.
> Required by:
> project :app
> > The consumer was configured to find a component for use during compile-time, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.ProductFlavor:store' with value 'play', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.4.2'. However we cannot choose between the following variants of project :react-native-camera:
> - generalDebugApiElements
> - mlkitDebugApiElements
> All of them match the consumer attributes:
> - Variant 'generalDebugApiElements' capability AwesomeProject:react-native-camera:unspecified declares a component for use during compile-time, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.4.2', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug':
> - Unmatched attributes:
> - Provides attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.ProductFlavor:react-native-camera' with value 'general' but the consumer didn't ask for it
> - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.ProductFlavor:store (required 'play')
> - Provides attribute 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr' with value 'generalDebug' but the consumer didn't ask for it
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
> - Provides attribute 'react-native-camera' with value 'general' but the consumer didn't ask for it
> - Variant 'mlkitDebugApiElements' capability AwesomeProject:react-native-camera:unspecified declares a component for use during compile-time, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.4.2', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug':
> - Unmatched attributes:
> - Provides attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.ProductFlavor:react-native-camera' with value 'mlkit' but the consumer didn't ask for it
> - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.ProductFlavor:store (required 'play')
> - Provides attribute 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr' with value 'mlkitDebug' but the consumer didn't ask for it
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
> - Provides attribute 'react-native-camera' with value 'mlkit' but the consumer didn't ask for it
> The following variants were also considered but didn't match the requested attributes:
> - Variant 'generalReleaseApiElements' capability AwesomeProject:react-native-camera:unspecified declares a component for use during compile-time, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.4.2':
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug'
> - Other compatible attributes:
> - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.ProductFlavor:store (required 'play')
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
> - Variant 'generalReleaseRuntimeElements' capability AwesomeProject:react-native-camera:unspecified declares a component for use during runtime, as well as
> attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.4.2':
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug'
> - Other compatible attributes:
> - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.ProductFlavor:store (required 'play')
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
> - Variant 'mlkitReleaseApiElements' capability AwesomeProject:react-native-camera:unspecified declares a component for use during compile-time, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.4.2':
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug'
> - Other compatible attributes:
> - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.ProductFlavor:store (required 'play')
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
> - Variant 'mlkitReleaseRuntimeElements' capability AwesomeProject:react-native-camera:unspecified declares a component for use during runtime, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.4.2':
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug'
> - Other compatible attributes:
> - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.ProductFlavor:store (required 'play')
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 45s
error Failed to install the app.
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).